# Is jOOQ forcedTypes a must to use postgres enum in java code?

Tags: java, sql, jooq

I have a spring boot app with jooq as DAO.

First, I create a enum type `role` in postgresql ([code](https://github.com/ocdexperience/sbjooqflyway-poc/blob/master/src/main/resources/db/migration/V4__Add_table_inventory_membership.sql#L1))

```sql
create type role as enum ('admin', 'user');

create table inventory_membership (
  user_id integer references user_profile (id),
  inventory_id integer references inventory (id),
  role role not null default 'user',
  primary key (user_id, inventory_id)
)
```

Then, as I want to use the java enum `role` in my app, I configure my `pom.xml` with below ([code](https://github.com/ocdexperience/sbjooqflyway-poc/blob/master/pom.xml#L126)):

```xml
<forcedTypes>
    <forcedType>
        <userType>com.ocdexperience.sbjooqflywaypoc.db.enums.Role</userType>
        <enumConverter>true</enumConverter>
        <includeExpression>role</includeExpression>
        <includeTypes>.*</includeTypes>
    </forcedType>
</forcedTypes>
```

Then I run codegen. Here is the `InventoryMembership` pojo. Note the `Role role` field.

```java
public class InventoryMembership implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 632233638;

    private Integer userId;
    private Integer inventoryId;
    private Role    role;

    ...
}
```

However, if I run codegen without the `<forcedTypes>` block in `pom.xml`, I will get `Object role` instead, which is not good.

```java
public class InventoryMembership implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -1258093557;

    private Integer userId;
    private Integer inventoryId;
    private Object  role;

    ...
}
```

Seems `<forceTypes>` block is a must. However, in [this example](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/blob/master/jOOQ-examples/jOOQ-spark-chart-example/src/main/java/org/jooq/example/chart/db/tables/Film.java#L116), there is no `<forceTypes>` block in `pom.xml`, but the generated code uses the generated enum automatically, instead of using `Object`.

Is that only due to the different jooq version? My project uses 3.12.1 vs the example project uses 3.13. Or is it because something else?

Thank you. My project is ready for up and run in https://github.com/ocdexperience/sbjooqflyway-poc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jOOQ can generate enum types from PostgreSQL database connections out of the box. The problem is, however, that you're using the `org.jooq.meta.extensions.ddl.DDLDatabase`, which parses your SQL and translates it to H2 behind the scenes. H2 has had a number of problems related to enum types in recent versions as they have just started supporting them. Currently, it is still not possible for jOOQ and H2 to produce the enum type in H2's dictionary views. A relevant bug is this one here:
https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/7917

If you want to profit from jOOQ's native enum support for PostgreSQL, I suggest conencting to an actual PostgreSQL database instead, for source code generation.

Comment: Switching to use postgresql solves the problem, as in https://github.com/ocdexperience/sbjooqflyway-poc/commit/4d43c444ee2734b28013b8bd136a073a2bf5165e.